# Equivalent definitions of manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

From Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, p.3:

[image]

**Question** Concerning the exercise; what if there is a point $x$ in our manifold $M$ such that it has a neighborhood $N$ that is homeomorphic to $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$? Then this neighborhood cannot be homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ or any open ball in $\Bbb{R}$. I cannot see why the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x \in M$ has a neighbourhood $N$ homeomorphic to $(0, 1)\cup(1,2)$; that is, there is a homeomorphism $\varphi : N \to (0,1)\cup(1,2)$. Now $\varphi(x) \in (0, 1)$ or $\varphi(x) \in (1, 2)$; without loss of generality, suppose it is the former. Now let $N' = \varphi^{-1}(0, 1)$. As $\varphi$ is continuous $N'$ is open, and as $\varphi(x) \in (0, 1)$, $x \in N' = \varphi^{-1}((0, 1))$. So $N' \subseteq M$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ that is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$, via the homeomorphism $\varphi|_{N'} : N' \to (0, 1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! My mistake results from not writing down my thoughts properly.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi \colon N \to (0,1) \cup (0,2)$ be the homeomorphism from the neighborhood $N$ of $x$ to $(0,1) \cup (0,2)$. Then $\phi(x)$ is either in $(0,1)$ or in $(1,2)$, let's say it's in $(0,1)$. Now $\phi^{-1}((0,1))$ is also a neighborhood of $x$ and it is, via $\phi$, homeomorphic to $(0,1)$.